# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in Chrome when use BrowserMobProxy for selenium test

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browsermob

I've created simple method for get network traffic from Chrome:

```
 public void saveNetworkTraffic() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/bin/chromedriver");
    String sFileName = "networklog.xar";

    BrowserMobProxy proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
    proxy.start(0);

    Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
    WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(driver);

    proxy.enableHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.REQUEST_CONTENT, CaptureType.RESPONSE_CONTENT);

    proxy.newHar("google.com");

    driver.get("http://google.com/");
    Har har = proxy.getHar();

    File harFile = new File(sFileName);
    try {
        har.writeTo(harFile);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
        System.out.println("Could not find file " + sFileName);
    }
}
```

When browser opens a page it shows an error "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"
on this step `driver.get("http://google.com/")` instead of usual google page in Chrome. 
I've tried to figure out the reason for the error, but according to the https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#using-with-selenium, my code should work fine.

Comment: Try https as well. I am assuming the proxy is not getting associated fine with the browser

Comment: The same behavior with https .

Comment: Same exact issue , with  ie and firefox as well

Comment: Does anyone find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Add this code, try it:

```
proxy.addFirstHttpFilterFactory(new ResponseFilterAdapter.FilterSource(new ResponseFilter() {
            @Override
            public void filterResponse(HttpResponse response, HttpMessageContents contents, HttpMessageInfo messageInfo) {}}, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, take a look about [how to format your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks#:~:text=Use%20the%20%7B%7D%20button%20above,%E2%8C%98%20K%20on%20OS%20X) and so, avoid to put images as code

Comment: This answer worked for me. Possibly should accept the answer. Why would this be needed?

Answer (score 0):

Your code look fine, try adjusting the dependencies like:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
            <artifactId>browsermob-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
```